# Node Fetch Post Request using Graphql Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, node-fetch

I'm trying to make a POST request with a GraphQL query, but it's returning the error `Must provide query string`, even though my request works in PostMan.

Here is how I have it running in PostMan:

[image]

[image]

And here is the code I'm running in my application:

```
const url = `http://localhost:3000/graphql`;    
return fetch(url, { 
  method: 'POST',
  Accept: 'api_version=2',
  'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
  body: `
    {
      users(name: "Thomas") { 
        firstName
        lastName 
      } 
    }
  `
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Here is the data: ', data);
  ...
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to make it so that the body attribute I'm passing in with the `fetch` request is formatted as `Text` like I've specified in the PostMan request's body?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The body is expected to have a `query` property, containing the query string. Another `variable` property can be passed as well, to submit GraphQL variables for the query as well.

This should work in your case:

```
const url = `http://localhost:3000/graphql`;
const query = `
  {
    users(name: "Thomas") { 
      firstName
      lastName 
    } 
  }
 `

return fetch(url, { 
  method: 'POST',
  Header: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/graphql'
  }
  body: query
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Here is the data: ', data);
  ...
});
```

This is how to submit GraphQL variables:

```
const query = `
  query movies($first: Int!) {
    allMovies(first: $first) {
      title
    }
  }
`

const variables = {
  first: 3
}

return fetch('https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cixos23120m0n0173veiiwrjr', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({query, variables})
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  return data
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

I created [a complete example on GitHub](https://github.com/graphcool-examples/scripts/blob/master/fetch/fetch-query.js).

Comment: Thank your sharing this solution. However, in the first example, I had to modify `'Content-Type': 'application/graphql'`. This was, in my case, within `headers` property. So, the `fetch` looks like...

fetch("/graphql", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
    })

Comment: What to do if I get an error: "message: "You are not authorized to make this call."? How to authorize when making fetch request to graphql endpoint?